# iOSで外部ブラウザ(safari)からアプリに自動で戻りたい

Tags: swift, ios

iOS(swift)で外部ブラウザでURL先でログイン後、自動で（ユーザの操作なし）で
元の外部ブラウザ呼び出し元に戻る方法がありますでしょうか？
外部ブラウザはsafariを使用です。

アプリの内部ブラウザでFacebookのログインボタン押下後、ダイアログが表示されないので、
外部ブラウザを考えています。
Chromeはインストールしていない状態です。

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 0):

FacebookのAPIなどを使用しているのでしょうか？
Callback URLをアプリ側のURL Schemeに設定してあげるとログイン後アプリを開いてくれます。

`twitter://`みたいな形です。